# Catia CATProduct & CATPart File Formats

Tags: c#, catia

I am trying to write a CatProduct/CatPart to step translator. I am writing this in c#. Just want to know if anybody knows what file format is a CatProduct or CatPart is saved in. The principal reason I want to read both file format is to establish the LASTSaveVersion contained within these files. Such information will allow me to translate using the correct Catia version of the CatBatchStarter dos utility. This windows application will ideally translate without entering the Catia modelling environment. This windows application will batch translate as well.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You can find LASTSaveVersion by simply opening your CATIA files in an text editor and search the string you mentioned. Look at the files in text editor, you can find also service pack, hot fix, FirstStreamed for V6 files and many other things...

Comment: I need to be able to establish the LastSaveVersion by programming means. Ideally C#. Been able to see this information in a text editor is really no good to me. it hast to be by programmatic means.

Comment: In vb.net you can use InStr(strTmp, "MinimalVersionToRead"). Idea is to read the binary file, search with InStr what you want and number how many characters you have to skip to find the version.

Comment: Hi, I want to write a catpart file loader for webGL library-threejs, but I don't find any file format spec online, how do you do it to write a translator? Is there any websites to learn it? I am new to catia programming. Thanks.

Comment: @David did you find any resource for what you were looking for?